# Is there a way to copy a ER diagram from one model to another model in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to copy an ER diagram from one model to another model in MySQL workbench. I have tried copying and pasting, but not been able to paste the copied results. Is there any option to do this?

I have tried copying and pasting, but not been able to paste the copied results.